# try and catch exceptions with jtextfield?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm making a simple GUI where the user has to enter 2 random strings of numbers and when the **done** button is pushed it will output those 2 strings. But how do I do this with try-catch method so that the user only can use numbers otherwise it will catch exceptions?

This is my code:

```
public Panel() 
{
    label1 = new JLabel("first string: ");
    label2 = new JLabel("second string: ");
    field1 = new JTextField(38);
    field2 = new JTextField(3);
    button1 = new JButton("done");

    ButtonP buttonP = new ButtonP();
    button1.addActionListener(buttonP);

    this.add(label1);
    this.add(field1);
    this.add(label2);
    this.add(field2);
    this.add(button1);
}

private class ButtonP implements ActionListener
{   
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  
    {
        System.out.println("String 1 " + field1.getText() + " and string 2 " + field2.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can look up the properties of `JTextField`, there is an option in which you can disable character entries in the field (i.e. only numeric values will be entered)

Answer (score 0):

The `isDigit(char)` method may be useful for you.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  
{
   for(char c: field1.getText().toCharArray()) {
       if(!Character.isDigit(c)) throw new WhateverException();
   }
   //Repeat this for field2's text as well
   //do other things with the strings, at this point they are valid
}
```

Replace the `WhateverException` with any exception you need thrown there.